# Error in "internal/modules/cjs/loader" when run single js-file if Docker, image node:12.4

Tags: node.js, docker

My first Docker project:

[image]

```
FROM node:12.4

CMD [ "node", "EntryPoint.js" ]
```

I created:

```
docker build -t hello_world .
```

When I run:

```
docker run hello_world
```

I get:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/EntryPoint.js
```

I don't understand what kind of relationship `cjs/loader.js` has. I just asked to run single ".js" file without any compiling or bundling like Webpack of TypeScript does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMD:

> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container

But when it tries to run `EntryPoint.js` inside your container it didnt find anything, try adding `COPY . .`:

```
FROM node:12.4

COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "EntryPoint.js" ]
```

- The first `.` character means the current directory and the second dot represents the current location on your virtual machine

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, nothing changed... "But when it tries to run EntryPoint.js inside your container it didnt find anything" - why?

Comment: Because the `Entrypoint..js` is on the host machine(your computer), and you want to run it on the container(another filesystem, it doesnt see the contents of the host machine), thats why you need to copy from your host machine to the container

Comment: "Because the Entrypoint..js is on the host" - got it! "you still getting the same" - I am sorry, everything works. It looks like just re-running container after corrections was not enough. I accepted your answer.